# Does Bing News Search API v7 support advanced operators?

Tags: bing-api, google-news, bing-news-search-api

Based on [Bing News API v7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference) documentation they support [advanced operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff795620.aspx).

For example searching for:

> "Dan Bilzerian" AND (women OR money OR "something wrong")

returns lots of results in Google News but nothing in Bing News.
Whereas

> "Dan Bilzerian" AND (women OR money)

return results in both where it is just the same thing for Google News.

Could you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Results are returned based on relevance.

Your use of OR makes it that "Dan Bilzerian" AND "something wrong" is likely the least relevant source of results.
So dropping that condition results in the same as using just the first 2 OR conditions.